# What shell uses cron on Ubuntu server?

Tags: bash, shell, cron

I made a bash script for Ubuntu server with C-style if-then clause `if (( $var = 6 ))`. It works perfectly from command line, but stuck when I made cronjob for this script. I changed it to `if [ $var -gt 6 ]` and then cron began to work. I assume that cron uses different shell, but what type and what other differences with bash?

Comment: Your question is better suited to [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/tour).

Comment: The `cron` manual documents this quite clearly.